# TortoiseSVN - adding single file to working copy from repositoy

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have this ongoing problem with my understanding of how TortoiseSVN works with working copy folders. Every time I try to do the below, I seem to delete everything in my working folder:

- Repository has files { File1, File2, File3 } and I checkout the folder first time, local working folder now matches
- Lots of other files are added over time, lets say I now have up to File100
- I want to only add File50 to my working folder; I try to select only that for checkout and I get the warning about the local folder not being empty, I then end up with only File50 in my local folder

What's the correct procedure for adding selectively files from the repository without altering the other files already in the folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: svn add file50; svn commit; and then you can do the checkout

Comment: I using the Windows TortoiseSVN GUI - I thought "Add" was to add new files from my local folder to the repository?

I want to add a single file from the repository to the local folder. I can't add a file with the same name because there's already one in the repo.

Comment: OK I have just worked it out - I opened repo browser and then dragged File50 from the browser into my local folder; it has now been added with version control history.